Two distinct prime integers between 1 and 20, inclusive, are selected uniformly at random. Find the probability their sum is even.
Question Two distinct prime integers between 1 and 20, inclusive, are selected uniformly at random. Find the probability their sum is even.
This question comes from a quant finance website
My Answer : the prime numbers are $\{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19\}$, the only times that the sum is odd is when $2$ is added to any other prime ($2 + 3$, $2 + 5$, $2 + 7$, etc..), giving us $7$ possible scenarios.
For the reverse ($3 + 2$, $5 + 2$, $7 + 2$, etc..) another $7$, hence the total is $14$
So the probability should be $$
\frac{64-14}{64} = \frac{50}{64}
$$
However, the answer on the website is $0.75$.
Maybe I'm missing something obvious?

You recieved 3 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, consider accepting the best answer and upvoting all useful answers you got. That's how the site works.

Most of your reasoning is correct, except for the number that you wrote out with no explanation: $64$. Two distinct prime numbers are chosen. So there are not $64$ options.

Doesn't that give $\frac{50}{56}$, which is about $0.89...$? Far from the $0.75$, proposed by that website.

@Dominique Where did you get $50$ from?

I copied it from the question itself, and you're right, it should be $42$, resulting in $\frac{42}{56}$, which equals $\frac{6}{8}$, which is $0.75$ indeed. Sorry for the mistake.

$$\frac{\binom{7}{2}}{\binom{8}{2}}=\frac{3}{4}$$
Sum is even then both must be odd. Since there are $7$ odd primes in $1\leq p \leq 20$, the number of distinct pairs is $\binom{7}{2}$
There are $8$  primes in  $1\leq p \leq 20$, the number of distinct pairs is $\binom{8}{2}$

Shortcut:
Arrange the $8$ primes between $1$ and $20$ randomly in a row.
Let's say that the first two primes in this row are the selected ones.
Then clearly the probability that prime $2$ is not among them is $\frac68=0.75$.
